# Call a DLL from Haskell

Tags: haskell, dll

I have a Windows DLL named `Foo.dll`. It exports (amoung other things) the following:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned int Version();
```

How do I write a Haskell program which calls this function and prints out the answer?

I managed to figure out that I can write this:

```
foreign import ccall "Version" cpp_Version :: CUInt
```

This compiles just fine, but utterly fails to link. This is not surprising; at this point GHC has *no idea* where the hell to look for this function. But I can't figure out what magic button I need to push to make this happen. Can anybody tell me how to get this to build sucessfully?

(I'm also not 100% sure whether the calling convention should be `ccall` or `stdcall`; what's the difference?)

Comment: Roughly speaking (and possibly inaccurate) `stdcall` is the calling convention of the Win32API, `ccall` is nearly everything else - certainly GCC (MinGW/MSYS) and Unix. OpenGL has used ccall [http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-June/016505.html] whether it still does I'm unsure. Likewise I'm unsure what .DLLs compiled by yourself with Visual Studio would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling with the following options *appears* to work:

```
ghc -O2 -L. -lFoo --make Wrapper
```

It appears that adding `-lFoo` tells GHC to look for a `Foo.dll` file, and adding `-L.` tells it to include the current directory in the DLL search path.

I am not 100% sure whether this is loading the DLL at runtime, or actually statically linking the DLL's code into the binary somehow. (!!)

Changing `ccall` to `stdcall` causes a bunch of warnings to be emitted (but the compiled code still works correctly). Thus, it *appears* that `ccall` is the correct thing.

I would still appreciate it if somebody could double-check that what I've written isn't complete nonsense...

Comment: Within your import statement you can state which header file the function comes from, as in: "`foreign import ccall "Version foo.h" cpp_Version :: CUInt`". I don't think this is required, but it's part of the FFI standard (see [8.5.1](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html)). You're right that `stdcall` is for Windows (but not 64-bit Windows), and `ccall` is used everywhere else. Dynamic linking is being used. At compile time a stub library for foo is created, which calls out to your .dll file. Test this by deleting foo.dll to be sure, but I think that's how it works.

Comment: The GHC docs clearly state that GHC completely ignores any include file specification. (Not that I _have_ an include file anyway...)

Comment: Okay. Having to specify libraries with `-l` is typical. Using a .cabal file makes things a little easier for me.